# How do I pass an Entity Object to a function in C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a public function that queries against a specific entity. I would like to replicate the function for any table I pass in but don't know how. Here is the working function I want to make dynamic:

```
public string MaxDepartment()
    {
        CPLinkEntities _context = new CPLinkEntities();
        results = _context.LOG_Departments.Max(t => t.LastUpdated); // hard coded
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(results);
        hex =  hex.Replace("-", "");
        return hex;
    }
```

What I would really like to do here is pass in an entity to query against. All entities have a timestamp. Here is what I envision it would look like but doesn't work:

```
 public string MaxDepartment(CPLinkEntities tableName)
    {

        var results = tableName.Max(t => t.LastUpdated);
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(results);
        hex =  hex.Replace("-", "");
        return hex;
    }
```

Calling the function from controller then would be:

```
CPLinkEntities context = new CPLinkEntities();
var tableName = context.LOG_Departments;
var maxDept = cf.MaxDepartment(tableName);
```

Comment: Could you create a interface or parent class that all of the tables that implement `LastUpdated` and have it declared there?

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, I'm not sure I understand what you are saying here. Can you explain the concept a bit more please?

Comment: I was describing Oleksii Aza's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it without changing any of your existing classes (if you can, see [Oleksii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21503526/80274)) is to manually create the expression tree and have it select the property you want.

```
public static string MaxDepartment<U>(IQueryable<U> table)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(U));
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "LastUpdated");
    var lambada = Expression.Lambda<Func<U, byte[]>>(property, parameter);

    var results = table.Max(lambada);
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(results);
    hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
    return hex;
}
```

You would call it via

```
using(CPLinkEntities _context = new CPLinkEntities()) //You forgot to dispose in your original example
{
    var max = MaxDepartment(_context.LOG_Departments);

    //Do whatever you want with max here.
}
```

This will fail at runtime if you try to pass in a table that does not have a `LastUpdated` property.

Comment: +1 for workable solution. The main drawback of this for me is lack of refactoring frendliness because of hard-coded name of LastUpdated property.

Comment: @Oleksii Aza, I was able to get this working. The reason for hard coding is because I plan on adding a timestamp field (called LastUpdated) to all of the potential lookup tables and this will allow me to store the table contents along with their max LastUpdated value in local storage and only do an ajax call to refresh them on the occasional times they change. The timestamp field isn't actually a DateTime filed, rather a binary field that simply increments by one any time a change is made to a table. That's why I didn't really consider your solution but thanks for the help

Comment: @AlanFisher You can still do his solution, you would just do `byte[] LastUpdated {get;set;}` in the interface instead. I only figured out the type of `LastUpdated` in my answer because a `byte[]` is the only thing `BitConverter` would take.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, Is there a real benefit for using his solution over the one you provided? I have it working and will consider looking at it if so. Thanks.

Comment: As he said in the first comment, If you ever update the field to be called something else, the automatic tools would update the field name where mine you would need to go in and remember to change the string by hand. Also my code allows you to pass in classes that do not implement `LastUpdated` and will cause a Excecption when you try and run the code, if you do the other solution you can only pass in classes that implement `ILastUpdatable` so you can't get a exception where you pass in a class that you should not have, you get a compiler error instead letting you know you made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should mark your entity with an interface like this:

```
public interface ILastUpdatable
{
   byte[] LastUpdated {get;set;}
}

public partial class LOG_Departments : ILastUpdatable
{
}
```

and then make your method expecting an object of type that implements an interface like this:

```
public string MaxDepartment<TLastUpdatable>(IQueryable<TLastUpdatable> updatables)
  where TLastUpdatable : class, ILastUpdatable
{
    var results = updatables.Max(t => t.LastUpdated);
    string hex = BitConverter.ToString(results);
    hex =  hex.Replace("-", "");
    return hex;
}
```

UPDATE:
Also you would consider to use it as extension method:

```
public static class MaxUpdatableExtensions
{
    public static string MaxDepartment<TLastUpdatable>(this IQueryable<TLastUpdatable> updatables)
      where TLastUpdatable : class, ILastUpdatable
    {
        var results = updatables.Max(t => t.LastUpdated);
        string hex = BitConverter.ToString(results);
        hex =  hex.Replace("-", "");
        return hex;
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
CPLinkEntities _context = new CPLinkEntities();
var results = _context.LOG_Departments.MaxDepartment();
```